# SQL Comparison of Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay, I have a situation when I need to compare a column from a table  with today's date.  If the value in a particular row is earlier than today (in other words, the date has already passed, I need to mark a virtual column with the phrase 'lapsed'

Below is the SQL (SQL Server 2012) that  I have been using:

```
SELECT
 datediff(day, sysdatetime(), policy_expiration_dt) As 'DayDiff'
,Case When 'DayDiff' < 0 Then 'Lapsed' 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

The first column that includes the datediff function makes the comparison and the second column marks it as lapsed if the date has passed.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @Kamran..why did you add `end` part to the `case` expression when it was absent in the question?

Comment: @vkp you needed the END otherwise you would have a syntax error in tsql SQL Server

Comment: @KamranFarzami, except you're putting words in the OP's mouth, thereby possibly totally changing their question.

Comment: You need to use something other than SYSDATETIME(). you probably will want to check if it was prior to an exact time, like 12:00 A.M (00:00)

Comment: @KamranFarzami; Policy here is that you do not change code posted in a question except for formatting. I rolled back your edit. As the poster did not explain a problem or ask a question, that *syntax error* might be the issue, and your edit removes it. That is vandalising the question.

Comment: @Martha I would not do it if I were vandalising OP's question

Comment: @KamranFarzami: you're assuming (possibly correctly, but we don't know) that the OP is having trouble because they're trying to use one column's alias in another column's `CASE` statement; but what if the actual problem they're having is the basic syntax of a `CASE` statement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

basically the order of how an sql statement is executed does not allow you to use the alias. so you will need to use the `datediff()` function in the CASE statement.

The order of sql queries execution is:

```
1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP
```

you need to do this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, SYSDATETIME(), policy_expiration_dt) AS 'DayDiff'
    , CASE
         WHEN DATEDIFF(day, SYSDATETIME(), policy_expiration_dt)  < 0 THEN 'Lapsed'
      END
FROM   TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: not sure why I got down voted. I guess someone did not like my comments  on the question ... meh!.... as for user2101538 thank you so much for accepting